# gmail api keeps changing the localhost address (python)

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

i followed the instructions to use a gmail oauth api in my application.

registering the url at Authorized redirect URIs doesnt seem to work as the number after localhost seems to change in every run (please see the image)

Problem is, when Google’s OAuth2 page is called, redirect_uri keeps getting set to http://localhost:/

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vetg7.png)

this error comes when i run the code from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Comment: Have you tried to add only "localhost" to the consent screen and credentials redirect_uri? without the port number?

Comment: I have tried that but it says it is an incomplete URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line 44 of the [quickstart.py](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/quickstart.py) script, assign to the server the same port that you will use in the credentials.

Then change the statement to be

```
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=<your-credentials-port>)
```

See [google_auth_oauthlib.flow](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html#google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.run_local_server) module.

Comment: Should this be a different port than where I am running my application? For example, my local frontend server runs on 8080 and my local backend server runs on 5000. When I access my app locally, I go to http://localhost:5000/[whatever]. When I use port 5000 as you describe, I get this error: OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Comment: Use a different port.  It can't be a port in use. Any port not in use will do. This is just for the flow.